# Time clusters in a randomised trial

Tags: clustered-standard-errors, random-allocation

In [cluster randomised trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster-randomised_controlled_trial), some clusters are treated whereas others are not. Usually, the clusters are geographical unit, e.g. villages. However, am I right that, in principle, the clusters could be time units, e.g. days?

As a concrete example, consider a politician who goes to a series of fundraising dinners, one every evening. (It's pretty exhausting!) At each dinner, they give one of two speeches, and decide which speech to give by flipping a coin. They then record all the donations raised on every evening.

To find out which speech is better, am I right that one should regress donations on the speech (a binary variable), clustering standard errors at the evening level?

As a bonus question, how important would it be to record the number of people at each dinner? If one does this, one would then have a series of zeros in the dataset corresponding to audience members who chose not to give anything.

Comment: How would you treat this as a cluster if you didn't have the number of people at each fundraiser? Without this seems your n for the experiment would just be the number of fundraisers.

Comment: @num_39 Even without knowing the number of attendees, one would still have data on all the donations. For example, at one dinner, the politician might receive donations of: £1, £5, £9.

Comment: Ah okay, so the average donation of the donors where n is the number of donors per cluster.

Comment: To be clear, I am interested in learning which speech maximises *total* donations. If the number of people per evening is fixed, this is equivalent to maximising average donations. (Even if the number is not fixed, the randomisation means that the number of people will be the same, in expectation, across evenings.)

Comment: If you're interested in total donations, then I'm back to the original question. How are you going use clustered standard errors if for each cluster (fundraiser) you have only one observation, total donations raised at that cluster?

Comment: If you want to keep it simple, just flip a coin and compare the averages. The problem here is that you might not have enough fundraisers to have a large enough sample. That's where you might look instead at average size of donations, then *n* is everyone who made a donation or average donations per person. Then you're talking about clusters and need cluster standard errors.

Comment: In any case, the clusters are the fundraisers, not time.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you could do a cluster randomized trial in the way you describe, as others have argued the clusters are really the dinners/the crowds. The time component is in that sense just a dangerous complication, because you could have the same people attending multiple dinners (and perhaps if you already donated you would donate less the next time, or perhaps hearing the same speech twice would bore you etc.), the speaker might get better at delivering the same speeches over time, might get more confident in delivering the speech that brought in large donations last night, or details of the previous speeches becoming public (making them less novel/compelling). These would violate some of the assumptions behind the standard CRT analysis (outcomes become dependent across clusters) and would require changes/adjustments + extra assumptions.

You definitely want to explain between cluster variability if you can. I.e. if you have some idea of expected donations, you'd want to adjust for that. If you know nothing else about the crowd, number of people attending might be a plausible proxy (then you'd be modelling donations per person) and probably also influences the variability of the total donations from one dinner. Something like estimated net net-worth of the people (or some even more specific indicator of likely donation size) might of course be even better.

Comment: Thanks for this. Regarding time effects ("the speaker might get better at delivering the same speeches over time"): I thought that this is allowed for if one clusters standard errors at the evening level? It seems analogous to the fact that, if one implements a treatment in some villages but not others (a standard CRT), some villages will be systematically different to others.

Comment: However, you'd get a time trend with outcome depending on how many previous times the same intervention was applied & the overall experiment outcome changes the longer the experiment runs (awkward, the # of clusters should surely not change the underlying answer?). So you'd be able to explain some variability by accounting for this, but you would not do so with standard CRCT methodology. This is more like treating multiple villages, but you implement the treatment poorly in the first few villages and keep getting better (or worse, if you get tired of doing the same thing/loose motivation).

Answer (score 1):

The current experimental design is more akin to a switchback experiment rather than cluster randomized trials.

Regarding your example, it appears reasonable to assume that there is no interaction between different fundraising dinners. This means that very few people attended multiple dinners, and those who attended later dinners were unaware of the previous ones. If this assumption does not hold, this paper, ([Design and Analysis of Switchback Experiments](https://www.hbs.edu/ris/Publication%20Files/WP21-034_20160b13-a86c-4a0d-b6e9-bbae288486c5_c93009c0-8003-43fd-bb1a-012c02d33b98.pdf)), may be helpful.

If we can assume that there is no interaction between different fundraising dinners, things can be very simple:

- let's generate some simulated data, the total donations in each fundraising dinner is: 90 * 2 / 7 * 0.1 + 30 * 5 / 7 * 0.1 = 4.7, and the mean donations per attendee is 0.1

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)

NT = 100 # number of fundraiser dinner

df = tibble(
  dinner_id = 1:NT,
  speech = if_else(runif(NT) > 0.5, 1, 0), # random allocation speech to each dinner
  is_weekend = if_else(runif(NT) < 2 / 7, 1, 0), # is dinner in week end?
  # here, assuming that fundraiser dinners held on weekends attract a higher number of attendees and lower mean donations rate.
  attend_n = if_else(is_weekend == 1, rpois(NT, 90), rpois(NT, 30)),
  resp_r = if_else(is_weekend == 1, 0.3, 0.4) + if_else(speech == 1, 0.1, 0.0), # on average, attendees of Speech 1 contributed 0.1 donations rate than those at Speech 0
  resp_n = rpois(NT, attend_n * resp_r)
)
```

> How important would it be to record the number of people at each dinner

if you have the number of people at each dinner, you can use it as a control variable for reduction variance, or simply regression donations per attendees

```
summary(lm(resp_n ~ speech + is_weekend + attend_n, df))
```

```
summary(lm(resp_n / attend_n ~ speech + is_weekend, df))
```

or you can regression on expended data, where each row corresponds to one attendee, with cluster robust standard errors

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

dfl = df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    resp_ny = list(c(resp_n, attend_n - resp_n))
  ) |>
  unnest(resp_ny) |>
  mutate(
    y = if_else(resp_ny == resp_n, 1, 0)
  ) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(resp_ny = list(1:resp_ny)) |>
  unnest(resp_ny) 
mod = lm(y ~ speech + is_weekend, dfl)
coeftest(mod, vcov = vcovCL, cluster = ~dinner_id)
```